# Setting build mode flags in angular app

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have a scenario in my angular app where I want to set some properties based on whether the app has been built in debug or release mode from a build task in my gulp file.

Basically I have code that should only be run when the app is built in debug mode (some code that uses the $interval service).

All I can think of right now is setting an angular constant to say what mode the app is running in, but it would mean changing it each time I want to build for debug or production\release mode. It would be nice if I can somehow get the build tasks to set some global that the client side angular app can get at.

I'm using Express as well, so I did wonder if maybe an environment variable could somehow be supplied to the client side code?

Has anyone encountered a similar situation and can offer suggestions for a suitable solution?

Comment: did you find any solution to this question @mindparse? I have a similar trouble/problem with a application we are developing..